# How to apply condition on a spark dataframe as per need?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am having a spark dataframe with below sample data.

```
+--------------+--------------+
|  item_cd     |   item_nbr   |
+--------------+--------------+
|20-10767-58V|       98003351|
|20-10087-58V|       87003872|
|20-10087-58V|       97098411|
|20-10i72-YTW|       99003351|
|27-1o121-YTW|       89659352|
|27-10991-YTW|       98678411|
|    At81kk00|       98903458|
|    Avp12225|       85903458|
|    Akb12226|       99003458|
|    Ahh12829|       98073458|
|    Aff12230|       88803458|
|    Ar412231|       92003458|
|    Aju12244|       98773458|
+--------------+--------------+
```

I want to write a condition like for each item_cd which are having hypen(-) should do nothing and for which not having hypen(-) should add 4 trailing 0's to each item_cd. Then take duplicates on both columns(item_cd, item_nbr) into to one dataframe and unique into other dataframe in pyspark.

could anyone please me with this in pyspark?

Comment: it would be more clear about what you want if you can provide a example output

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it could be done:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

data = [("20-10767-58V", "98003351"), ("20-10087-58V", "87003872"), ("At81kk00", "98903458"), ("Ahh12829", "98073458"), ("20-10767-58V", "98003351")]
cols = ["item_cd", "item_nbr"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)
df.show()

df = df.withColumn("item_cd", when(~df.item_cd.contains("-"), F.concat(df.item_cd, F.lit("0000"))).otherwise(df.item_cd))
df.show()

unique_df = df.select("*").distinct()

unique_df.show()
w = Window.partitionBy(df.columns)

duplicate_df = df.select("*", F.count("*").over(w).alias("cnt"))\
    .where("cnt > 1")\
    .drop("cnt")

duplicate_df.show()
```

Input df (added duplicate):

```
+------------+--------+
|     item_cd|item_nbr|
+------------+--------+
|20-10767-58V|98003351|
|20-10087-58V|87003872|
|    At81kk00|98903458|
|    Ahh12829|98073458|
|20-10767-58V|98003351|
+------------+--------+
```

Unique df:

```
+------------+--------+
|     item_cd|item_nbr|
+------------+--------+
|Ahh128290000|98073458|
|20-10767-58V|98003351|
|20-10087-58V|87003872|
|At81kk000000|98903458|
+------------+--------+
```

Duplicates df:

```
+------------+--------+
|     item_cd|item_nbr|
+------------+--------+
|20-10767-58V|98003351|
|20-10767-58V|98003351|
+------------+--------+
```